# Invalid string in encoding image to base64 - Swift 4

Tags: swift, encoding, base64, nsdata, decoding

my issue is when I try to encode an image to base-64, it generate a long string (up to 200,000 lines) and it doesn't work in the decoding, it generate a nil image! even I try to resize the image to a smaller size but still it doesn't work!

Here is my image encoding code

```
let image = imageView.image
let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)! as NSData
let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
```

The decoding code:

```
let processImage = user.value(forKey: "processImage") as! String // image from json 
if let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: processImage, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
          let image: UIImage = UIImage(data:dataDecoded as Data,scale:1.0)!
          print(image.size)
          self.myImage.image = image }
```

Comment: Do you store the Base64 encoded string in some database? Have you verified that the retrieved string is identical to the one initially computed? Perhaps the database has a size restriction?

Comment: Yes I stored it in MySql database, but Im sure the problem isn't from the DB because I've print the base64 string before storing it and try to decode it in base64 image converter website then it generate a null image. Also I've used the same technique in Android to store encoded string in the same database and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Following Steps:

**Step :- 1** First Fetch the NSData from it

---

There are three Possibilities:

**1. Using Image Name**

```
 let image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"imageNameHere")!
//Now use image to create into NSData format
let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
```

**2. Using NSURL:**

```
//Use image's path to create NSData
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string : "urlHere")!
//Now use image to create into NSData format
let imageData:NSData = NSData.init(contentsOfURL: url)!
```

**3. Image picked from image picker**

```
 let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage    
 let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
```

---

**Step:-2** Then Encode:

```
    let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
    print(strBase64)
```

**Step:-3** Then Decode:

```
    let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: strBase64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
    let decodedimage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)
    yourImageView.image = decodedimage
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Still doesn't work. In this line "let image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"imageNameHere")!" what should be the name of the image if I took the image from UIImageView?

Comment: From what source you are picking image? From image picker or any other source?

Comment: Yes from  image picker

Comment: @NouraAziz Have edited the Answer, please look into that